# How do I preserve materialized value in custom Sink?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Could you please tell me how to preserve materialized `Future[Int]` in example like this ?

```
val test: Sink[Int, NotUsed] =
  MergeHub.source[Int].grouped(100).to(Sink.fold(0L) { case (count, items) => count + items.sum }).run()
```

I'd like to get `Sink[Int, Future[Int]]`. I looked at `viaMat`, `toMat` and couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `run()` the whole graph in the same place, just use `toMat` + `Keep.right`

```
val result: Future[Int] =
    MergeHub.source[Int].grouped(100).toMat(Sink.fold(0) { case (count, items) => count + items.sum })(Keep.right).run()
```

if you need to reuse your "group + fold" sink, you need to strip out the source and the `run` call

```
  val sink: Sink[Int, Future[Int]] =
    Flow[Int].grouped(100).toMat(Sink.fold(0) { case (count, items) => count + items.sum })(Keep.right)
```

More info in the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#combining-materialized-values).